# border-width: inherit not working

Tags: html, css, border

I am trying to have the child element taking the `border-width` of parent element.

I have reduced my problem to following code.

```css
.first, .second {
    border-color: red;
    border-width: 5px;
    background: #eee;
}

.first span {
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: inherit;
    border-style: solid;
}

.second span {
    border-width: inherit;
    border-color: green;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<p class="first"><span>'border-color: inherit' works</span></p>
<p class="second"><span>'border-width: inherit' does not work</span></p>
```

As you can see, that `border-color: inherit` works fine for `span`. But, `border-width: inherit` is not working for the same `span`.

I have tested in chrome, firefox and ie.

[Jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jashwant/tzq6Lodg/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Taken from MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-width

> border-bottom-width: the absolute length or 0 if border-bottom-style is none or hidden

Since the parent has no border-style defined, the inherited width is 0. If you specify a border style to the parent its width will be inherited

Comment: I definitely tried it earlier, but it didn't work. I may have messed up something.